# How to check for duplicate values in a list ignoring a specific value?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm trying to determine if a list has duplicate values. My list consists of numbers only and I only care to find non-zero duplicates. So if my list is `[0,4,0]`, I don't want my program to consider it having duplicates (since I'm ignoring the `0`s), but if my list is `[3,0,3]`, my program should tell me it has duplicates.

I tried using this code:

```
Mylist = [0,4,0]
if len(Mylist) == len(set(Mylist)):
    print('The list does not have duplicates')
else:
    print('The list has duplicates')
```

The code works but it considers the `0`s which I don't want.
I know I could create a loop with a few lines of code that checks each value, but I'm wondering if there's an easy and short way to do this.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it overrides a builtin type.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it.

Comment: A very inefficient way: `len(l) == len(set(l)) or len(l) == len(set(l)) + l.count(0) - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove the `0`s from the list.
Note that the second line in the code uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
Also `list` is the name of a Python built-in function, so It would be better to use a different name for your list.

```
my_list = [0,4,0]
my_list_no_zero = [value for value in my_list if value != 0] # this uses list comprehension
if len(my_list_no_zero ) == len(set(my_list_no_zero )):
    print('The list does not have duplicates')
else:
    print('The list has duplicates')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid creating a new list with filtered values and build upon a set incrementally and short cut early using something like:

```
any(map(lambda L, I={0}, S=set(): (L not in I and L in S) or S.add(L), your_list))
```

This'll return `True` as soon as an element is seen more than once that shouldn't be ignored (the `I={0}` part) or `False` otherwise (eg: all non-ignored elements are unique).